# Redirect after successful transaction?

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, redirect

I was trying to `redirect` the page after `successful transition` to custom page **"Thank You"**.

> We have 2 methods. `Paypal` & `Vica / Master Card`.

In `Paypal` there is an option to set redirect page after successful transition.

```
Profile -> Website Payment Preferences
```

But, How can I redirect the page, If transition done via `Vica / Master Card` ?